# http url for js file inside a war?

Tags: javascript, url, war

Suppose a WAR layout like so:

```
foo.war
-->/WEB-INF
   -->/classes (..)
   -->/js
      -->bar.js
   -->index.jsp
   -->web.xml
```

Now suppose the WAR's virtual directory is /blah on server example.com (i.e. http://example.com/blah).

What is the HTTP URL of `bar.js`, one that would be used in a `<script src="">` tag that `index.jsp` might serve up? http://example.com/blah/js/bar.js doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no URL that will point to this.  Everything within `WEB-INF` is not exposed to the outside world.

Rather, if you organised the WAR layout like this:

```
foo.war
-->/WEB-INF
   -->/classes (..)
   -->web.xml
-->/js
  -->bar.js
-->index.jsp
```

Then you could access your Javascript as http://example.com/blah/js/bar.js.

P.S. You won't be able to access index.jsp either, the way you have things set up at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. I must've misinterpreted a link about packaging using maven-war-plugin.

Answer (score 3):

You must **NEVER** put a **JS** inside **WEB-INF** directory.

As written in Servlet specifications, whatever you put inside **WEB-INF** directory will never be directly available to the external world. Only local application resources go there.

So if you want some **JS** file accesible from outside, put it directly at WAR's ROOT. Something like this:

```
foo.war
-->/js/
    -->bar.js
-->/WEB-INF
    -->internal resources here
```

The URL to access **JS** will be something like:

```
http://YOUR_IP:8080/foo/js/bar.js
```

This of course could vary depending on how you setup your war deployment on your application server.

You **do** however put **JSP** files inside **WEB-INF** directory, only to invoke them from Servlets (you can't directly access them either) with something like:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/index.jsp");
```

This is a common practice if you don't want people accessing directly your **JSP** files from outside.

Comment: Thanks. I must've misinterpreted a link about packaging using maven-war-plugin.