# Inclusion of java script path in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, inclusion

I have  a web application WAR in below structure

Conversion.War
|
    Conversion.War\ index.html

```
Conversion.War\META-INF

Conversion.War\WEB-INF\web.xml

Conversion.War\WEB-INF\actual.jsp

Conversion.War\WEB-INF\js\convertmap.js
```

When I access the application I am redirecting to `actual.jsp` and in `actual.jsp` I need to include this `convertmap.js` which is not working.

I tried below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ConvertMap.js"></script>
```

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891907/http-url-for-js-file-inside-a-war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving

```
Conversion.War\WEB-INF\js\convertmap.js
```

to

```
Conversion.War\js\convertmap.js
```

That *should* match the context for

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ConvertMap.js"></script>
```